# Using SELECT subquery in WHERE clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to use the result of a SELECT subquery in my WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
ID,
post_parent as parent,
post_status,
(SELECT post_status as p FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = parent) as parent_status
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
AND post_status = 'inherit' 
AND post_parent != 0 
AND parent_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

But it doesn't seem like MySQL is aware of the parent_status column, the error is:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'parent_status' in 'where clause'
```

However, if you remove AND parent_status = 'publish', you get the results back including the parent_status column:

```
ID      parent  post_status parent_status
1908    1904    inherit     publish
1907    1904    inherit     publish
1906    1904    inherit     publish
1905    1904    inherit     publish
1902    1900    inherit     publish
....
```

The goal of the query is to to grab the post_parent ID in the outer query, and then in the subquery grab the post_status of the parent. This is WordPress and I'm trying to list media attachments only if they have a parent and that parent is published.

I may be doing something fundamentally wrong with trying to use the SELECT subquery with the WHERE clause. Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause.  You have several options.  The best in this case is to use the MySQL extension that allows the logic in the `having` clause.  You also have a logic problem in the subquery.  I think you mean:

```
SELECT ID, post_parent as parent, post_status,
       (SELECT post_status FROM wp_posts wp2 WHERE wp2.ID = wp.post_parent) as parent_status
FROM wp_posts wp
WHERE post_type = 'attachment'  AND post_status = 'inherit'  AND post_parent <> 0 
HAVING parent_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY post_date DESC;
```